# CLLocationManager's pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically property always false in Swift (iOS8 / iOS7)

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I try to set the location manager's pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to true in Swift but it seems to have no result.

Also, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically):

> The default value of this property is true.

However, the default value in reality seems to be false and also there seems to be no way of setting it to true:

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
println(manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically) // prints false

manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
println(manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically) // prints false
```

How to set this property to true?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running it in the simulator, it will always show "`false`".

Try running it on the device, like I just did, it will always say "`true`".

NOTE: This is applicable to iOS7-iOS11, and Objective-C as well.

Comment: Actually on my iPhone 4 it always says "false", but I hope it is just an iPhone 4 problem. What device did you run the code on?

Comment: I used an iPhone 5S... do you have other devices to test with?

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will soon test in a 4S and try to find other devices too in the coming days. I will let you know, of course.

Comment: pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically is always false in an iPad Air (iOS 8 / iOS 9) and it is by default true in an iPhone 6 (iOS 8).